# Send float parameter through SqlDatasource.InsertParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, sqldatasource, detailsview

Hi I am trying to insert a float value into database through SqlDatasource.InsertParameter but after SqlDatasource.Insert() function is executed I only see the Integer part of it inserted in database. I have also debugged and checked that before the execution of SqlDatasource.Insert() the value stored in SqlDatasource is float. Below are my code:

Function from data layer:

```
     public static SqlDataSource DataSourceInsert(string sp, string[,] param)
{
    float f;
    ds = new SqlDataSource();
    if (cns.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        cns.Open();
    ds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cns"].ConnectionString;
    ds.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ds.InsertCommand = sp;

    for (int i = 0; i < param.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        ds.InsertParameters.Add(param[0, i], param[1, i]);
        ds.InsertParameters[param[0, i]].DefaultValue = param[1, i];
        if(float.TryParse(param[1, i],out f))
            ds.InsertParameters[param[0, i]].Type = System.TypeCode.Double;
    }
    ds.Insert();
    return ds;
}
```

Parameter P

```
protected void DV_ItemInsert(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    string procname = "spAddandInsertProduct";
    string[,] p = new string[2, 5];
    p[0, 0] = "ProductName";
    p[1, 0] = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    p[0, 1] = "Description";
    p[1, 1] = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    p[0, 2] = "IsPublished";
    p[1, 2] = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    p[0, 3] = "Quantity";
    p[1, 3] = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).Rows[3].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    p[0, 4] = "Price";
    p[1, 4] = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).Rows[4].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    ds = SQLInteractor.DataSourceInsert(procname, p);

    ProdAdmin_insertDV.DataSource = ds;
    ProdAdmin_insertDV.DataBind();
    GV_databind();
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `param`?

Comment: Thats not readable. Its a string array.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what `param` is. Also, please [edit] the details into your question.

Comment: Done. Added both the complete functions

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check:
a) What culture setting are you working with, and do the string representations of those float values match up? This could be your error.
b) Less likely is that you need to operate with double, either to handle the conversion to double on the DB side better, or because your data values require it.